# Gaussian processes and generating functions from a distribution?

Tags: bayesian, simulation, stochastic-processes, gaussian-process

Some points in Rasmussen book on Gaussian processes are confusing, when he says that the first step in some GP regression is

> In Figure1.1(a) we show a number of sample functions drawn at random
>   from the prior distribution over functions specified by a particular
>   Gaussian process which favours smooth functions ...

What is meant by drawing functions from a distribution?

Since a function is infinite dimensional--in the calculus of variations sense--then there could be an infinite dimensional set of basis functions that represent the function. I am thinking of something similar to the way that Fourier transforms can be used to convert any piecewise smooth function into an infinite sum of sines and cosines. In the case of a stochastic process, this could be a decomposition such as the Karhunen-Loeve transform to convert a stochastic process into a sum of basis functions.

So is drawing a function from a distribution really mean just drawing random coefficients for the basis functions--subject to some constraints. What kind of mathematical algorithm is used to actually draw a function from a distribution?

Comment: There are many approaches to generate random functions. One is indeed to pick a functional basis like wavelets and draw the coefficients in this basis. Another is to use a stochastic differential equation. If you have heard about the Brownian motion, this is one example of a random function. Concerning prior and posterior, once a distribution is selected as a prior, it can be updated when the function is observed at some points in its support.

Comment: @Xi'an thanks for answering my question. That helps a lot. Yep, I understand SDEs as well as wavelet bases. So we can adjust the covariance matrix for the stochastic component in the update step. But then how does the interpolation between points work? Do we simply drop any random functions that do not interpolate between the test points, or is there some other nicer way to force all random functions to hit the test points?

Comment: Fixing values of $f$ means moving from Brownian motion to Brownian bridge.

Comment: Okay excellent. Thanks for the insight. I have not looked at Brownian bridge in lately, so I will refresh my memory. Thanks again.